# GSuite Vault API: Any way to get a list of users on hold programmatically?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-vault-api

Currently, the [Google Vault API](https://developers.google.com/vault) does not provide a way to get a report of all users in a G-Suite tenant or domain who are on hold in one or more matters.  This information is currently available only via the [admin interface for Google Vault](https://ediscovery.google.com/discovery/) under Reports/User Holds.  It would be great to be able to obtain this report via an API call in JSON format rather than only via the admin UI.  Am I missing something or is this functionality already available?

Respectfully, please keep in mind that suggesting that I perform API operations to search all matters and iterate through the users on hold in each matter to obtain this information is not the answer I am looking for.  There should be a quicker, more efficient way to get this information since such a report is already available via the UI.  I am simply asking if there is a way to get this same information programmatically via the APIs/automation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Vault API does not have a method for that. The only way to retrieve this information is to list all matters and iterate through them, as you already mentioned.

#### File a feature request:

It's not uncommon for a feature to be present only in the UI. If you want to see this implemented on the API, I'd suggest you to report it on Issue Tracker's [Vault component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/197903/manage#basic).

I looked through the issues of this component, and it looks like this hasn't been requested yet. There's currently a somewhat related feature request, but not exactly what you're looking for:

- [Audit reporting functionality](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120242241)

#### Update:

The original poster filed a feature request in Issue Tracker. I'm add this to the answer in order to give it more visibility.

To anyone who would like to see this feature implemented in the future, I'd suggest starring the issue (star on the top-left) in order to help prioritizing it:

- [Vault API: Need API method to return list of all users who have active holds as available in Vault UI](https://issuetracker.google.com/169333424)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Iamblichus.  Do you work for GSuite support by any chance? It doesn't indicate so in your bio.

Comment: Thank you, here is why I asked.  Why would your suggestion (of which I already surmised was the only available option) of looping through any number of matters (which theoretically be in the hundreds) and then subsequently iterating through all the users in those matters be beneficial to either me (quota limits) or GSuite (increased exponential traffic and overhead for having to make such requests for each user I need this info for, which could be thousands).  Isn't it better to simply expose the functionality utilized in the UI to the API since it already exists? I ask with all due respect.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I've created the feature request as suggested in the Issue Tracker for Vault: https://issuetracker.google.com/169333424

Comment: @tfrancois It's a workaround. The functionality you desire is not available yet, and meanwhile the iteration process, if not ideal, is the only way to go.

Comment: @tfrancois Thank you for creating this FR. I updated my answer with this so that it gets more visibility.